# Change font color in Scribble (html backend)

Tags: racket, scribble

Is there any way to change the font color in scribble with an HTML backend?

(More specifically, I want to put a large red WARNING label in the manual for a library.)

Comment: I know you can do it with a class paired with a CSS file, but do you mean you want to create an inline style in the output?

Comment: Either way works for me. I would just like to have it work in the documentation for a library. (Using #lang scribble/manual.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out you can do this directly in scribble without using a backend dependent solution. The trick is to use [styles](http://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/core.html?q=style#%28tech._style%29) that have [`color-property`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/core.html?q=color-property#%28def._%28%28lib._scribble%2Fcore..rkt%29._color-property%29%29).

Using [`elem`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/base.html?q=elem#%28def._%28%28lib._scribble%2Fbase..rkt%29._elem%29%29) to set the style, [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35301596/apply-a-style-in-scribble), you can create a `colorize` function, that sets the color of your text.

```
(define (colorize #:color c . content)
  (elem #:style (style #f (list (color-property c)))
        content))
```

And then you could use it like this:

```
@colorize[#:color "red"]{WARNING}
```

There is also [`background-color-property`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/core.html?q=background-color-property#%28def._%28%28lib._scribble%2Fcore..rkt%29._background-color-property%29%29) you can sue to set the background of the text.

Answer (score 1):

As Alexis mentioned, you can use a `class` paired with a Cascading Style Sheet (CSS) like so:

```
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
   <!-- that's to link our styles to the webpage. -->
</head>
<body>
   <!-- some time later... -->
   <p class = "example">test</p> 
   <!-- the rest of the website -->
```

And in `mystyle.css`:

```
.example{ /* select all tags with the "example" class */
     color: #FF0000; /* change font color using hex value */
     background-color: #552222; /* change background color using hex value */
}
```

Now, this would be great if we were able to use multiple files.  But, if you want to have it all in one file, we can send that same information in a `<style>` tag:

```
<head>
   <!-- no need to link our styles, since they're embedded in the webpage. -->
</head>
<body>
   <style>
     .example{ /* select all tags with the "example" class */
        color: #FF0000; /* change font color using hex value */
        background-color: #552222; /* change background color using hex value */
     }
   </style>
   <!-- some time later... -->
   <p class = "example">test</p> 
   <!-- the rest of the website -->
```

There's another way to embed it, but you shouldn't use it.  Ever.  This is always the correct way.

See http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_examples.asp if you need anything more from the CSS side of things.

Comment: This doesn’t have anything to do with Scribble, which is what was asked about in the question.

Comment: I appreciate your eagerness to help. But yeah, this has nothing to do with Scribble, and more to do with just coloring HTML tags. Good answer though (just to a different question.)

Answer (score 1):

Manually creating a [`style`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/core.html?q=style#%28def._%28%28lib._scribble%2Fcore..rkt%29._style%29%29) struct containing an [`attributes`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/core.html?q=attributes#%28def._%28%28lib._scribble%2Fhtml-properties..rkt%29._attributes%29%29) property appears to work:

```
#lang scribble/base

@(require scribble/core
          scribble/html-properties)

@para[#:style (style #f `(,(attributes '([style . "color:blue;"]))))]{blue text}
```

Comment: Sad that this is the only way to do it. (There really should be a backend independent way to do it anyway.) But thank you.

Comment: Apparently you can do this without specifically using your back end. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35301776/288439