# Apply a style in scribble

Tags: racket, scribble

I have the following [style](http://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/core.html?q=style#%28tech._style%29) which should change the color to red (using [`color-property`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/core.html?q=color-property#%28def._%28%28lib._scribble%2Fcore..rkt%29._color-property%29%29):

```
(define red
  (style #f
         (list (color-property "red"))))
```

How can I apply that style to a word in my text. Say I want `WARNING!!!` to appear in red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`elem`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/base.html?q=elem#%28def._%28%28lib._scribble%2Fbase..rkt%29._elem%29%29) to apply a style to a piece of text.

So, your text could look like this:

```
@elem[#:style red]{WARNING!!!} This is a warning.
```